# Google Chrome 64 / 67 different behavior for HTTP2

Tags: google-chrome, web, azure, c#, api

We are using WebAPI with angularJS in our application. With Chrome version 64 we can see H2/ HTTP2 protocol used, but after update i.e. Chrome 67, we can now see SPDY. What will be the reason for this change ? If we downgraded chrome to 64 then working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

#### What will be the reason for this change?

It's a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704146).

> Chrome Version: 59.3047
>
> What steps will reproduce the problem? (1) Visit a page (e.g.
>   https://www.accuweather.com) that results in pulls from the memory
>   cache
>
> Observe: Requests that hit the memory cache show "spdy" as the
>   protocol Expect: No such claim, because we don't enable SPDY in Chrome
>   any more.
>
> getProtocol() here
>   https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/devtools/protocol/network_handler.cc?l=381&rcl=7569715801917d9c4dd1bdc0182bd38ff3e43cae
>   returns SPDY if the was_fetched_via_spdy flag is true, but that flag
>   is a bit of a lie; it's true for QUIC (verified) and probably H2
>   (didn't look) as well.
>
> If we cannot fix the protocol annotation on the MemoryCache responses,
>   we should probably change the default fallback to either "" or "h2"
>   since the latter is most likely.
>
> ...
>
> Looks like somewhere in the cache layer it's flagging it wrong. I'll
>   look into it.
>
> ...
>
> This issue still exists in 69.0.3477.0 and also applies to disk-cached
>   resources.
>
> ...
>
> I also encountered this issue in Chrome 67. It seems that not only
>   disk-cached and memory-cached resources were shown as "SPDY"。I had
>   already disabled cache.
>
> https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/PYCV9EuYers

Source [704146 - DevTools Network tab shows SPDY for memory-cached resources - chromium - Monorail](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704146)

> In Chrome 67, the HTTP protocol shown in the Network Tab of the inspector seems wrong. When my website loads a HTTP2 resource, Network Panel shows that it was using SPDY. When I copied the same resource url and opened it in new tab, Network Panel shows that it was using HTTP2. Additionally, in chrome 66, these two situations were shown as HTTP2.

Source [The Network tab of inspector shows wrong HTTP protocol in Chrome 67 - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/PYCV9EuYers)